# How to type-switch values with generic types

Tags: go, interpreter, evaluation

I'm building a simple interpreter that evaluates addition expressions. The interpreter will support simple pure functions as values.

One thing I want to do is use generics to lift the types of the expressions (number vs lambda) into Go. (e.g. the `Number` AST node is an `Expression[float64]`)

I'm running into an issue type-switching the expression in my evaluator function, however:

```golang
// ... some definitions omitted...

type Expression[TNative NativeType, TValue Type[TNative]] interface {
    Node
    GetType() TValue
    IsExpression()
}

type Number struct {
    Expression[float64, NumberType]
    Value float64
}

func Eval[TNative NativeType, TValue Type[TNative]](node Expression[TNative, TValue]) Value[TNative, TValue] {
    switch node := node.(type) {
    case Number:
        return &NumberValue{Value: node.Value}
    }

    return nil
}
```

What I would expect to happen in this case is for the `switch` statement to match the type with `Number` in `Eval`. If it matches, then the values of `TNative` and `TValue` would be known, so NumberValue (which is `Value[float64, NumberType]`) would be a valid return type.

However, when I try to run the code, I get an error about impossible switch cases:

```
./eval.go:5:7: impossible type switch case: Number
    node (variable of type Expression[TNative, TValue]) cannot have dynamic type Number (wrong type for GetType method)
        have GetType() NumberType
        want GetType() TValue
./eval.go:6:10: cannot use &NumberValue{…} (value of type *NumberValue) as type Value[TNative, TValue] in return statement:
    *NumberValue does not implement Value[TNative, TValue] (wrong type for GetType method)
        have GetType() NumberType
        want GetType() TValue
```

I'm not sure why this is happening other than that TNative/TValue cannot be inferred using type-switching. If so, then is there no way to dynamically determine them?

Thanks in advance.

Edit to add: I've tried making the switch statement `switch node := any(node).(type)`, and this gets rid of the first error, but not the second.

Edit to add: Example with all the definitions here - https://code.garrettmills.dev/garrettmills/go-interp-eg/src/branch/master/interp.go

Comment: to dynamically inspect a value's type at runtime, you can use the reflect package. I haven't checked yet how it behaved on generic types, though.

Comment: It's possible to make your code compile, but then you have a lot of problems when trying to call `Eval`. An answer that addresses the error message you posted would fall short immediately after. You should edit your question to include a **minimal** reproducible example.

Comment: So one problem is that the type switch needs to be valid over all possible parameters for `TNative` and `TValue`. This is clearly not the case because `Number` can only be valid for a specific `TValue` and `TNative`. What you want is something like dependent types or HKTs; something which Go doesn’t have. FWIW your code would not work as is in Rust either, because of the issue I mentioned above.